# How to prevent dangling pointer of captured "this" destroyed by shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class Event
{
public:
    void RegisterHandler(std::function<void(bool)> handler)
    {
        mHandler = handler;
    }  
    void Fire(bool value)
    {
        if (mHandler)
        {
            mHandler(value);
        }
    }
private:
    std::function<void(bool)> mHandler;
};

class EventListener
{
public:
    explicit EventListener(const std::string& value) : mValue{value} 
    {
        std::cout << mValue << " constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~EventListener()
    {
        std::cout << mValue << " destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    void Listen(Event& event)
    {
        event.RegisterHandler(std::bind(&EventListener::Handler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
private:
    void Handler(bool value)
    {
        std::cout << mValue << " event " << value << std::endl;
    }
    std::string mValue;
};

int main()
{
    {
        Event event{};

        auto handler {std::make_shared<EventListener>("first")};
        handler->Listen(event);

        event.Fire(true);
    }
    {
        Event event{};

        {
            auto handler {std::make_shared<EventListener>("second")};
            handler->Listen(event);
        }
        std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello from dangling pointer");

        event.Fire(false);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
first constructor
first event 1
first destructor
second constructor
second destructor
om dangling pointer event 0
```

[Test this code online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WuXEnHnAhzVH0bZY#result-container-tab-permlink)

---

`std::enable_shared_from_this` seems to be a solution.

```
class EventListener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<EventListener>
{
public:
    void Listen(Event& event)
    {
        event.RegisterHandler([sharedThis{shared_from_this()}](bool value)
        {
            sharedThis->Handler(value);
        });
    }
```

Output:

```
first constructor
first event 1
first destructor
second constructor
second event 0
second destructor
```

[Test this code online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iCnedqsaUygWYj3p#result-container-tab-permlink)

---

The two rules I am aware of:

1. After capturing `this` make sure you remove/unregister/cleanup the capture in destructor.
2. Use `shared_from_this()` to don't bother about the lifetime.

Are there better solutions? Any advice how to prevent/handle such cases?

Comment: I'd start by following the observer pattern rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Usually you have some container which is responsible for the lifetime of listeners, and your construction of the listener passes ownership to the container. Better yet, the actual listener registration usually relies on weak pointers, so that even if a message is received in the small window while the container is shutting down the listener, it can cleanly handle that the weak pointer can't be resolved any more.

Comment: The comment from Gem Taylor is spot on for the question asked.  (The question, as asked, seems to be coming from "how do I implements events in C++ like how they are done in C# and .NET".  I may be off base, but that's the vibe I got.)  Regardless, Boost Signals2 may also be of interest, since it is an implementation of the signal/slot concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing a listener on a broadcaster, you need to arrange for unregistration.  Having the broadcaster store a shared pointer to the listener is a bad plan, as it means that the listener's lifetime is suddenly controlled by the broadcaster.  That kind of code leads to resource leaks, where unused resources stay around after nobody cares about them.

Instead, I typically have the broadcaster store weak pointers.  When it broadcasts, it first discards all stale weak pointers, copies the list of targets, then (in an unlocked context) sends messages to each listener.

This can be done by either allowing the listener to pass in a shared pointer resource or have the broadcaster return a shared pointer token.

```
using token=std::shared_ptr<void>;
template<class...Args>
struct broadcaster {
  token listen( std::function<void(Args...)> );
  void shared_listen( std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(Args...)>> );
  std::size_t operator()(Args...) const;
private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  mutable std::vector< std::weak_ptr<std::function<void(Args...)>> > listeners;
};
```

flesh that out and you get a decent broadcaster that is pretty easy to use.

The listening class either stores a `std::vector<token>` holding its listening rights, or builds a `std::shared_ptr<std::function<...>>` (possibly via the aliasing ctor of shared ptr) and passes that in.

In both cases, deregistration occurs using RAII and lifetime of listener object is not at all controlled by broadcaster (except, possibly, for short window during actual broadcast).  Plus, the deregistration doesn't depend on broadcaster outliving listener.

There can be some memory resources that last longer than ideal (as the reference counting block is kept alive by weak_ptr, and if you use make_shared that includes the direct memory footprint of the object), and this isn't suitable for frameworks where widgets have 1000+ broadcasters with utilization in the 0.1% range, but it works really well for less extreme cases.

Answer (score 0):

Those two rules mentioned in the question are all that is to this subject.

The code example is not architecturally correct, as stated in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991344/how-to-prevent-dangling-pointer-of-captured-this-destroyed-by-shared-ptr?noredirect=1#comment90934048_51991344).